# Excel Macro - Take a snapshot of Particular Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have come around a very strange requirement in my Excel Dashboard.

> I have a some data in a Range in a particular sheet. I need to take a
>   snapshot of it and display it as an Image in all other sheets at top.

I know I can simply copy & paste the range but that kind of Header is creating some issues while hiding columns on the sheets.

Any solution/trick for that same?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific! What kind of "some issue"? Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Range has a .CopyPicture method.

Or use the Camera tool:

```
Sub Tester() 
    Sheet1.Range("D5:E16").Copy 
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste Link:=True 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can this be used to paste the picture in email body drafted by excel?

Comment: I'd try the CopyPicture method for that

Comment: @TimWilliams i'll give it a try. If I cant figure it out I may post a question and link it here! Thanks