# Excel macro to take a screenshot of specific cells and save as image file

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an Excel file and I need a macro that takes a screenshot of just cells G3 to J14 of the current sheet and saves it as an image file (any common format will do) to the folder containing the Excel file with a file name matching the contents of cell B3.

Comment: Have to point out that I don't quite see a question in your posting. Please remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get pointed advise on coding errors. You can start with looking a this posting on how to paste as picture and go from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990503/excel-macro-take-a-snapshot-of-particular-range. Once you have your code if you have any specific issue you can post it here to get help. Regards

Comment: Here is another posting that I found after a Google search that specifies code to save a picture from clipboard to the file system: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?25275-Saving-Clipboard-data-as-picture. With both of these links you should be able to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
Sub Macro1()
    myFileName = "chrt.png"
    Range("G3:J14").Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
End Sub
```

But you may need to resize or edit the resulting picture to meet your needs.  You also may want to delete the Chart when you are done.

Comment: please stop feeding the vampires

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't understand.

Comment: low effort/low quality Q's should be closed, _not_ answered.  Answering perpetuates the problem

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I will pay more attention to the question's quality in the future.