# I am looking to loop through a slicer and select the next item and the next to print a pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I have a slicer linked to 2 pivot tables. I want to loop through the slicer from the first item to the last item and print the corresponding tables.

I have tried the following code:

```
Sub Slicerloop
    Dim sI As SlicerItem, sI2 As SlicerItem, sC As SlicerCache
    Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_UID")
    With sC
        For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
            For Each sI2 In sC.SlicerItems
                If sI.Name = sI2.Name Then sI2.Selected = True Else: sI2.Selected = False
            Next        
        Next
    End With        
End Sub
```

There are no errors messages, but this does not select the next entry and thus change the pivot table.

Comment: You can find an answer at the following link below. Please make sure to add the .ShowAll Items or .ClearManualFilter before the 2nd FOR loop.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375474/6908282

Comment: Your code is almost the same as the linked one. It indeed selects each `SlicerItem` individually, but you don't stop your loop then (after the first `Next`), and therefore it automatically selects one after the other and you don't recognize the effect.

Comment: I added an answer with desired functionality to save the pivottable's range as picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this you can loop over all sliceritems and use their individual caption for a screenshot of your pivottable.

```
Private Sub LoopAllSlicerItemsAndCapturePivottable()
    Dim sc As Excel.SlicerCache
    Dim si As Excel.SlicerItem, siDummy As Excel.SlicerItem
    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
    Dim co As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim wsBlank As Excel.Worksheet

    Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_UID")
    Set pt = sc.PivotTables(1)

    ' add a blank sheet to get a blank Chart instead of PivotChart later 
    Set wsBlank = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
        sc.ClearManualFilter
        For Each siDummy In sc.SlicerItems
            siDummy.Selected = (si.Name = siDummy.Name)
        Next siDummy

        ' now only 1 sliceritem is selected and can be used
        With pt.TableRange2 ' or TableRange1
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            Set co = wsBlank.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, .Width, .Height)
            co.Select
            co.Chart.Paste
            co.Chart.Export _
                fileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Whatever " & si.Caption & ".png", _
                filtername:="PNG"
            co.Delete
        End With
    Next si

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsBlank.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```